Which data providers provide full Sentinel 3 SLSTR product?
I am looking for data providers that provide Sentinel 3 SLSTR dataset in the raw L1 - RBT SAFE format. We are using some existing providers with following issues:
Copernicus Dataspace: Lately the speed I get from them are quite slow.
Sentinelhub: Doesn't seem to provide the raw radiance bands which I need for my application, only provide cropped section
Creodias: Facing similar issues to copernicus dataspace i.e. data speed coming slow.
Are there any other providers apart from these providers which provide Sentinel-3 SLSTR dataset?
I tried to download from sentinelhub, but it gives only the cropped section. I wanted access to the raw radiance bands. I tried using other providers mentioned by the EODAG library that I use to download the dataset.
EODAG: https://eodag.readthedocs.io/en/stable/
SENTINEL-3: https://sentinel.esa.int/web/sentinel/user-guides/sentinel-3-slstr
